# Nokia / HERE maps: text and standard markers

Tags: javascript, marker

I could not create text marker and standard marker together. I can create alone standard or text marker but did not create both. My codes below:

```
function OnAjaxCompleted(result) {
if (result == null)
    return;

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var newMarker = null;
    var textMarker = null;

if (SelectedMap == "here") {
        if (result[i].Y > 90 || result[i].X > 90)
            continue;

        newMarker = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(
            new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(result[i].Y, result[i].X), {
                id: result[i].Id,
                draggable: false,
                icon: GetIcon(result[i].Icon_Id, result[i].bCommError, result[i].Speed, result[i].bIdle),
                anchor: new nokia.maps.util.Point(12, 12)
            }
        );
        map.objects.add(newMarker);

        textMarker = new TextMarker(
            new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(result[i].Y, result[i].X),
            result[i].Plaka,
            result[i].Plaka.width("12px sans-serif") + 12,
            20,
            {
                brush: { color: "#FFFFFFAA" },
                pen: {
                    strokeColor: "#000",
                    strokeWidth: 1
                },
                textPen: {
                    strokeColor: "#000",
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
                    offsetX: 6,
                    offsetY: 15
                }
            }
        );
        textMarker.set("anchor", new nokia.maps.util.Point(8, -12));
        map.objects.add(textMarker);
    }
}
```

}

The result variable is a list and have 80 elements. This function correctly load first 20-25 parameter but after break down.
Function result : [incorrect marker result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7310878/errhere.jpg)

Comment: The code for adding a `StandardMarker` and `TextMarker` from the [examples page](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/markers/extending-marker-to-text-marker.html) looks OK. Could you check or **add a link** to your AJAX response to see if that is where the problem lies. Also would a [Combined Icon and Text Marker](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#text-on-icon-marker__index) work better for you?